# pass parameters into the middle of a url

Tags: php, json, class, parameters, get

ok, I have a url that calls a webservice, lets say that url is:

http://url.com/products/[productid]?Lanaugae=english$username=username&token=1234

What I'm doing is calling the webservice inside a function, grab the product ID from a get and pass it in and then fire off the function that does all the curl goodness.

The troublesome bit is the productid is in the middle of the url, which I declared globally, and the curl bit fires from another function. I think in .net you could say {0} in the place of [productid] then when you call the variable tell it what should go into [productid], can I do something similar in PHP?

So at the top of my class I want:

```
$this->url = 'http://url.com/products/{0}?Lanaugae=engish$username=username&token=1234';
```

this in my function I want to do something like:

```
$productid = $_GET["productid"];
$responseData = $this->curl_dat_thing($this->url, $productid);
```

...This possible/make sense?

Comment: Let's says it doesn't make sense. Can't you simple say: $newUrl = $this->url.$myvars? That way you can concatenate your values.

Comment: That said, a get value isn't positional, you can add it to the end of the string as example =)

Comment: Even if you get that part working, the `$username=username` is going to mess you up. Use `&username=username` just like you did with `&token`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) like this:

```
$this->url = 'http://url.com/products/%s?Lanaugae=engish$username=username&token=1234';

$productid = $_GET["productid"];
$responseData = $this->curl_dat_thing(sprintf($this->url, $productid));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's inside `curl_dat_thing()` but you should do this:

```
$this->url = 'http://url.com/products/'.$productid.'?Lanaugae=engish&username=username&token=1234';
```